# Two dimensional dynamic array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Im having Troubles populating a two-dimensional Array on the fly.

I have a list of 26 names and want to randomly divide them into 5 Groups of 5each, with one having 6.
I then want to use each Group to write the names into a separate sheet.
My Background is PHP and JS, so the Need to dim or redim an Array doesnt come as easy to me.

```
Dim KlasseA() As String
Dim KlasseB() As String
Dim KlasseC() As String
Dim KlasseD() As String
Dim KlasseE() As String


For i = 1 To 20
   If Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2) <> "" Then      

        pick = ((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

        If pick = 1 Then
            KlasseA(i) = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3) & ", " & Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2)
        ElseIf pick = 2 Then
            KlasseB(i) = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3) & ", " & Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2)
        ElseIf pick = 3 Then
            KlasseC(i) = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3) & ", " & Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2)
        ElseIf pick = 4 Then
            KlasseD(i) = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3) & ", " & Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2)
        ElseIf pick = 5 Then
            KlasseE(i) = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 3) & ", " & Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2)
        End If
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

' push the 5 Arrays into a master Array. Use 1 Loop inside a Loop Output the 5 Groups to 5 sheets
```

Im having two Problems here:

1. How can i create "higher" Array where i can push the 5 lower Arrays into, to then Loop over all the names (i.e. one final Loop instead of 5).
2. The code above will populate the sub-Arrays in a non-fluid manner, i.e. a bunch of array-index are left out (due to the i).

Ideally, i would want to create a 2d-Array and use this inside the Loop instead of the flawed workaround above.
Can someone advice me ?

Comment: Shuffle your array using http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShuffleArray.aspx and then just loop over it and place the values on the sheets - five each sheet then six on the final one.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases when sample data together with expected results would have gone a long way towards explaining the situation. This is what I envision you are attempting.

```
Option Explicit

Sub mcrKlasse()
    Dim Klasse() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, pick As Integer

    ReDim Klasse(1 To 5, 1 To 20)

    With Worksheets(1)
        For i = LBound(Klasse, 2) To UBound(Klasse, 2) 'for 1 to 20
            If CBool(Len(.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)) Then
                pick = ((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
                Select Case pick
                    Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
                        Klasse(pick, i) = Join(Array(.Cells(i + 1, 3), .Cells(i + 1, 2)), ", ")
                End Select
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        'redimension the array in case less than 20 were filled
        ReDim Preserve Klasse(1 To 5, 1 To i - 1)

        'stick them back on the worksheet
        With .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
            .Resize(UBound(Klasse, 1), UBound(Klasse, 2)) = Klasse
        End With

        'flip them (transpose) and stick them back on the worksheet
        With .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
            .Resize(UBound(Klasse, 2), UBound(Klasse, 1)) = _
                Application.Transpose(Klasse)
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

The code runs through the data but tbh, I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Basicly, i have a sheet of of 26 names and need to randomly divide them into 5 Groups, whereas the 5 Groups should have the same amount of members, if possible.
I know realize that randomly picking the new Group does not result in Groups with the same size.
thanks